# Removing catkin workspace

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created 2 catkin workspaces, then I decided to rm -rf one of them. It seems like there should be a better way to remove it because some environment variables are lingering around with that path, namely $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

1. Where does ROS set $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH so I can remove any references to it now that I've deleted it?
2. Is there a proper way to delete a catkin workspace so that all environmental variables are cleaned up?

**Answer:**
I 'sourced' both my devel workspace 'setup.bash' and the groovy installation 'setup.bash', when I removed that line from my .bashrc (as the commenter said) CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH was no longer set.

Deleting build and develop and simply calling catkin_make again, then sourcing my workspace only in .bashrc fixed it.

Thank you! :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66012/removing-catkin-workspace/) by [plunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/5257/plunder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-06-26**:
If the problem persists after a reboot, the problem is probably in your ~/.bashrc. Can you post the contents of that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This stuff can get very confusing and cause serious errors.

The general recommendation when switching workspaces is always to open a new shell, and source the relevant `setup.bash`. For catkin, that is normally in `devel/` subdirectory.

**UPDATE**: If you are sourcing the correct `setup.bash` in your `~/.bashrc` and creating a new shell (or rebooting) does not work, there must have been something wrong when you originally created your workspace. The usual error is having forgetten to source the appropriate lower-level `setup.bash` before running `catkin_make`.

That is an easy mistake to make. When I find myself in that situation, I do one of these recovery procedures:

- Create a new workspace, more carefully this time.
- Delete everything but the `src/` subdirectory, source the correct dependency, then re-run `catkin_make` or `catkin_init_workspace`.

There may be other solutions, but I find that hacking around in the various generated files just creates frustration and wastes time.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [plunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/5257/plunder/) on 2013-06-26**:
Well, I've already done that but when I reboot the the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH persists, I'd really like to clean that up, do you know how?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-06-26**:
I you have a `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` after reboot then you are setting it in your `~/.bashrc` most likely. Look in that file to see if you are `source`'ing any `setup.bash` files. If you are, delete or comment that line out and open a new terminal. Rebooting is not necessary, just open a new terminal.

**Comment by [plunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/5257/plunder/) on 2013-06-26**:
I am sourcing 2 files in my .bashrc, 1 is /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash the other is my current catkin_workspace ~/ros_ws/devel/setup.bash.. I'll try removing these when I get home and see if this solves my issue

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-26**:
If things were set up correctly, the workspace should source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.sh for you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those using `catkin tools`, an easy solution is: `catkin clean --deinit` at the directory of your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [hayaalsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/38304/hayaalsh/) with karma: 11 on 2018-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1